# bash script clobbering variable in echo

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

I am trying to write a script which reads the hostname of the remote machine and then uses that result in following commands. However, the variable seems to be corrupted or something.

Here is an example of what is happening:

```
sbaker@eye004:~/workspace/fire_trunk$ REMOTE_HOSTNAME="`ssh $REMOTE 'hostname'`"
sbaker@eye004:~/workspace/fire_trunk$ echo "before $REMOTE_HOSTNAME after"
```

prints (note the prefixing whitespace):
`" after sbaker-PC"`

```
sbaker@eye004:~/workspace/fire_trunk$ echo $REMOTE_HOSTNAME
```

prints:
`"sbaker-PC"`

I am wondering why the variable seems unusable and doing weird things (if the after word is longer than the before word, it writes over the top of the characters).
I would expect the first echo to print: `"before sbaker-PC after"`.

Am I just doing something stupid here?
I am using bash on ubuntu 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put it through `od -c` you'll see that it's actually returning `sbaker-PC\r`. The CR at the end is causing it to return the cursor to the first column before echoing the rest of the text, obscuring the "before". As for *why* it's adding `\r`, perhaps the file giving the hostname on the other side was saved with DOS line endings (CRLF) instead of *nix line endings (LF).

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out. The remote host is a windows host running cygwin sshd. Is there an easy way of cleaning these stray characters up?

Comment: You could shove it through `tr`, telling it to delete any instances of `\r`.